# constructors didn't get called with () but get called it with {}?

Tags: c++, constructor

So I make some statement `CLASS(OTHERCLASS());` and it didn't call the constructor at all. I change the `()` to `{}` then it call all the construct step. Why?

here's the test code

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int g = 0;
struct A    {
    A() {
        cout << "A C" << endl;
        g++;
    }
    ~A() { cout << "A D" << endl; }
    int a = 0;
};

struct AA {
    AA(const A& a) {
        cout << "AA C" << endl;
        g++;
    }
    ~AA() { cout << "AA D" << endl; }
    int aa = 0;
};
struct AAA
{
    AAA(const AA& a) {
        cout << "AAA C" << endl;
        g++;
    }
    ~AAA() { cout << "AAA D" << endl; }
    int aaa = 0;
};


int main() {

    cout << g << endl;
    {
            AAA{AA{A{}}};     // <=== constructors get call
    //  AAA(AA(A()));      //<<=======this one didn't invoke any constructors
    // AAA aaa=AAA(AA(A()));    //<=== this one invoked constructors
    }
    cout << g << endl;
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

with `AAA(AA(A()))`  the output is

```
0
0
```

with `AAA{AA{A{}}}` or `AAA aaa=AAA(AA(A()))`the output is

```
0
A C
AA C
AAA C
AAA D
AA D
A D
3
```

what's wrong with the one `AAA(AA(A()))`?

Comment: Look up "the most vexing parse in C++". https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bcpp%5D+the+most+vexing+parse

Comment: @RSahu I did read some before posting, those  I read   talk about confusing with declaration. But I don't see  the case I made `AAA(AA(A()))`  confuse with the function declaration ,I just invoke the constructor.

Comment: @DetectiveKing YOU think you are invoking constructors, that is your *intent*, but that is not what the COMPILER thinks. IT thinks you are declaring a function named `AA` that returns an `AAA` and takes as input a function that returns an `A`. This really is the "most vexing parse" in action. If something *looks* like a function declaration, it is *treated* as a function declaration. So, using `()` in this particular context causes ambiguity that leads to "vexing". With `{}`, there is no such ambiguity. That is why the `{}` syntax was added to the language, to avoid "vexing" confusion.

Comment: @RemyLebeau thanks for the comment. I did some test and  it show that  `AAA AA(A())` == `AAA(AA(A()))` ,it's my first time to know that this two are equivalent .